# help with openmp compilation problems

Tags: openmp

I'm trying to use omp in my C code and am having a problem:
in the code i have #include 
but when i try to compile with:

g++ -fopenmp -g -c parallel.c

I get cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "fopenmp"
and when i try:

g++ -g -c parallel.c

I get an error for both:

omp.h: No such file or directory, and
malloc not declared in this scope

i tried with gcc with -fopenmp and get the same error. without the -fopenmp i still get the missing omp.

Answer (score 4):

[OpenMP](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/openmp) is only supported in gcc 4.2 and higher. You might need to upgrade your compiler.