# Can't use openmp in c++ project

Tags: c++, openmp

I've included openmp to my project. I've got -fopenmp in compliler flags.

g++ -std=c++0x -O3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -march=core2 -fopenmp -ffast-math -fPIC

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    MatrixXd frame = frames.row(i);
    output.row(i) = dem(frame);
}
return output;
```

And I have this output when compiling.

```
hello.cpp:(.text+0x2d88): undefined reference to `omp_get_num_threads'
hello.cpp:(.text+0x2d8f): undefined reference to `omp_get_thread_num'
./hello.o: In function `demodulateMatrix':
hello.cpp:(.text+0x315f): undefined reference to `GOMP_parallel_start'
hello.cpp:(.text+0x316c): undefined reference to `GOMP_parallel_end'
```

I've tried to add -fopenmp flag to the linker and I have this output with it

```
g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fopenmp,’
make: *** [libhello.so] Error 1
```

GCC version is 4.8.2 right now.

Comment: Are you using GCC version < 4.2? If so, possible duplicate of [help with openmp compilation problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375165/help-with-openmp-compilation-problems). Try `gcc --version`.

Comment: I've got the latest stable release of gcc. 4.7 or something. Definitely not 4.2

Comment: OK, well it would still be useful to find out exactly what version you have and add it to the question.

Comment: What linker are you using? Make sure it’s the right version, and it’s the C++ linker (`g++`). Clearly compilation *does* work for you, so GCC correctly recognises the `-fopenmp` flag. Provide a *complete* minimal example, along with *all* command line calls you issue.

Comment: I'm using eclipse CDT. The linker is default I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass `-fopenmp` to the linker as well. It looks like you tried to do that, but you have a syntax error that causes the linker to see `-fopenmp,` (with a stray comma at the end). Check your makefile.

(Also you seem to pass `hello.cpp` to the linker instead of `hello.o`, so your code is compiled twice.)

Comment: Good spot on the `,`!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now all working.